# ' in sed appearing in the wrong place

Tags: linux, sed, debian

I am trying to set an IP in a file with sed.  I am running this command

`sed -i 's:$dbserver='':$dbserver='10.0.0.2':' t.conf`

but when I look in t.conf the line is

`$dbserver=10.0.0.2''`

Anyone know why the two single quotes are appearing at the end of the line?

I am running Debian Linux

Comment: use `"s:$dbserver='':$dbserver='10.0.0.2':"` instead

Comment: I had to escape the $ as well but yup!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose the second `sed` argument in double quotes:

```
sed -i "s:$dbserver='':$dbserver='10.0.0.2':" t.conf
```

This way `$dbserver` will be substituted with its value before being passed to `sed`, and the single quotes won't need escaping.

If you want `$dbserver` to appear literally in the conf file, preceed the dollar signs with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This worked, I did need to leave $dbserver in there.  I love it when the solution winds up be very simple! :-)